# Find out whether or not a "unit" was issued or returned on any given date (excel)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have exported all of my transactions (issuances and returns) onto an excel spreadsheet and based on a specific "unit's" serial number I need to find out whether the "unit" was "issued" or Returned at that (random) time.

For Example:

```
Sheet1
A           B                C                
Dates       Serial Number   Type Trans
6/11/2011   000023          Issued
7/25/2011   000504          Returned



Sheet2
A                B                    C
Serial Number    [Random Date 1]      [Random Date 2]
000023           Issued               Issued

Break            Break                Break

Total Issued     [amount gone]        [amount gone]
```

I need to find out if any of my serial numbers were checked out or were they checked in during the random date? If this doesnt make any sense let me know. FYI I do not need to know if a transaction occured on the random date but rather the condition (issued out or returned to me) on the random dates. I've tried various arrays of max, if and vlookup's and i can't get this to work. Someone save me please!

**EDIT:**
So after trying what Ron has suggested, I need to clarify what I am trying to achieve. I have ~90 Units. On any random date, I am trying to determine how many units were gone (issued). I don't need to find out if a transaction occured on the random date. I am trying to do some trend analysis to determine whether i can taylor down how many unit's i have. For example, today I have 47 units issued out. But all my system will allow me to see is the current stats. So I extracted my entire history of transactions to try and to this analysis. Once I have the  formula to populate Sheet2!B2 i can then apply it to all of my serial numbers and dates and then just use countif to determine how many i had in my custody vs how many i had issued on the random date. Thats my plan anyways...

Comment: Yes they are sorted oldest to newest. There are about ~1565 transactions.

Comment: The formula to count the number of units that show Issued or Returned on any given date would be a simple COUNTIFS.  But I don't understand the rest of what you have written as far as how you want your results formatted. =COUNTIFS(Dates,$F2,TypeTrans,G$1)  where F2 is the Date in question and G1 is either Issued or Returned.  Please show clear example of what you want for results.

Comment: So we know I have 90 unis. As activities need these I issue them out. I am trying to find out if i have too many. at the current moment only about half of them are issued out. So I want to pick random dates in history and find out on that random date how many units I have issued out. Does that make any sense? I'll throw a link to the file so you can see what i have if that will help https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5RZumoc9tOcMGEwRTYtMTFPUTA/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Couldn't access that file link.  But how are you computing the number "[amount gone]"?  If it is the total of those issued minus those returned prior to the random date, just use the COUNTIFS formulas I have previously provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you will be entering some date into B1 and C1

In that case, enter this formula in B2.  Fill across to C2. Then select B2:C2 and fill down as far as required.

Also note that, as displayed, Sheet1!B:B and Sheet2!A:A should be formatted as text, or the serial numbers should be prepended with a single quote mark.

```
B2:    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((Dates=B$1)*(SerialNumbers=$A2)),TypeTrans),"")
```

Where Dates Refers to: Sheet1!$A$2:$A$n, SerialNumbers Refers to: Sheet1!$B$2:$B$n, TypeTrans Refers to:  Sheet1!$C$2:$C$n  (n is the lowest row number with Dates or you can use a dynamic reference).

**EDIT:** And since, based on your comment, I don't fully understand the layout of your results, here is an image of what your data and results would look like in the manner I do understand and described above:  (The top window is Sheet1; and the lower window Sheet2).

[image]

Comment: Instead of a date in Sheet2!$B1 I would prefer to have either "Issued" or "Returned" depending on its status at the given (random) date. Although there are close to 1600 transactions there are only about 90-100 serial numbers... If that helps...

Comment: Kindly describe your layout, because with the result of the determination in Sheet2!B1, I don't understand where the formula would obtain the dates, nor how one associates the result in B1 with the serial number in A2.  Also, what is the significance of the ?'s you show in sheet2!B2:C2 ???

Comment: Also, you can just modify the formula I provided so that it is obtaining the "random date" from some cell other than B1; and the Serial number from some cell other than A2.

Comment: My apologies. I did mean b2. Your screenshot looks exactly like what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, so after i applied your formula i realized this will only return a value when a transaction happened on the given random date. which isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm not even sure what I am looking for is possible but... Instead of knowing whether a transaction occured on that date, what I need to know is: given a random date, out of the ~90 unit's i have, how many were gone (issued) on that random date. I am trying to do some trend analysis to see if I can taylor down how many unit's I have. i do appreciate what i've learned from you already though!

Comment: That would be a simple COUNTIFS formula

Comment: the countifs will work once i get the data populated but other than manually searching my data is there going to be a way to populate the data automattically?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you have no data, what is there to search?  As far as populating your data automatically, that depends on the source of your data.  Perhaps you could post a workbook at some public site, and post a link here, showing precisely what you are trying to communicate to me.

Comment: @bloodox Just to let you know, I can now access the link that you posted previously on Jan 16 in your comment, but I am not able to download the file; nor does it seem to show any indication of exactly what you want for results, or what the inputs to that computation might be.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcvjtl03lj10qym/PODS%20GHG7%203%20Year%20Trend%20Analysys.xlsx

Comment: The file can now be downloaded.  But there is no sheet indicating what you want for results, nor what you have tried and what you are expecting.